# Pass values of kendo grid to popup window

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I have implemented a kendo grid and context menu in my MVC5 page. I open a window  on click of the Update Status menu. I need to retrieve the requestid and couple of other fields from the selected row in the pop up window. I would also need to show a drop down control with values. Whats the best way of doing it

Grid

```
div class="requestgrid" id="requestGrid">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.RequestViewModel>()
.Name("GridRequest")
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound(o => o.RequestID).Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CountryCode).Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.SalesOffice).Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CustomerNumber).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ProjectName).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ProjectContent).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ContractStartDate).Width("140px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.Priority).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.NameOfResponsiblePerson).Width("170px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.Status).Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedBy).Width("110px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedDate).Width("110px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ModifiedBy).Width("110px");
})
//.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
//.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
.Scrollable()
.Groupable()

.Selectable(selectable => selectable
    .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
    .Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
    .Events(events => events
    .Change("onChange")
)
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(t => t.RequestID))
        //.Create(update => update.Action("Team_Create", "Admin"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Requests_Read", "Request"))
    //.Update(update => update.Action("Team_Update", "Admin"))
    )
)
```

**Context Menu**

```
  @(Html.Kendo().ContextMenu()
        .Name("RequestMenu")
        .Target("#GridRequest")
        .Filter("tr")
        .Orientation(ContextMenuOrientation.Vertical)
        .Animation(animation =>
        {
            animation.Open(open =>
            {
                open.Fade(FadeDirection.In);
                open.Duration(500);
            });
        })
         .Items(items =>
         {
             items.Add()
                 .Text("Edit");

             items.Add()
                .Text("Update Status");

         })

         .Events(e =>
         {
             e.Select("onSelect");

         })
    )
```

Javascript

```
 function onSelect(e) {
        var grid = $("#GridTeam").data("kendoGrid");
        var requestId;

        switch ($(e.item).children(".k-link").text()) {

            case "Edit":

                var grid = $("#GridRequest").data("kendoGrid");
                var column = grid.columns[0];
                var selectedBackup = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                requestId = selectedBackup.id;
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("EditRequest", "Request", new { id = "_id_", status="Edit" })'.replace('_id_', requestId);
                break;
            case "Update Status":
                //alert("Work in progress");
                //$('#window1').data('kendoWindow').center().open();

                var myWindow = $("#window");

                //e.preventDefault();
                //var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

                //kendo.bind($("#window"), dataItem);



                   myWindow.kendoWindow({
                    width: "400px",
                    height: "180px",
                    title: "Update Request Status",
                    modal: true,
                    visible: false,
                    actions: ["Minimize", "Maximize", "Close"],

                }).data("kendoWindow");
                   myWindow.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it *almost* right, only by two details:

1. If you bind the contextMenu's target to the grid's container, you'll never be sure which row user did clicked. I suggest you to bind to your grid's rows(TR) instead, e.g. `#GridRequest tbody tr`;
2. I'm afraid `e.currentTarget` doesn't exists or returns `undefined` in that context. You should use `e.target` which will point to the clicked row if you did what I suggested above. Then you could get your *dataItem* as follows:

   ```
   grid.dataItem(e.target);
   ```

Check out [this demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uNUfO) with my suggestions working.

Comment: If I add  .Target("#GridRequest tbody tr") , my context menu stops working

Comment: @Tom, well, thats wierd. I thought it would work like the javascript api.

Comment: Yes. Quite strange

Comment: @Tom but, if you make a grid row to be selected as a requirement to use menu's actions, you can use the other suggestion I did in the demo, which gets the grid's selected row and not the menu's target element.

Comment: I did try your example but you too have used #grid tbody tr. so how will that work for me

Comment: @Tom keep your menu that way, just try `var selectedRow = grid.dataItem(grid.select())` inside the `onSelect` but the grid's row must be selected.